# Controller behavior(different data from Factory) which depends on view

Tags: angularjs, json, view

This is the Factory.

```
angular
 .module('WordsFactory', [])

 .factory('WordsFactory', WordsFactory);

 function WordsFactory($http) {

 exports = {
     basics1Data: null
 };

 exports.getWordsBasics1 = function () {
     return $http.get('data/basics1.json')
         .success(function (data) {
             exports.basics1Data = data;
         })
         .error(function (data) {
             console.log('There was an error!', data);
         });
 };
 exports.getWordsBasics2 = function () {
     return $http.get('data/basics2.json')
         .success(function (data) {
             exports.basics1Data = data;
         })
         .error(function (data) {
             console.log('There was an error!', data);
         });
 };

 return exports;

}
```

Controller:

```
angular
  .module('app.words', ['WordsFactory'])

  .controller('WordsController', WordsController);

 function WordsController(WordsFactory) {

  var vm = this;

  WordsFactory.getWordsBasics1()
      .then(core);


  function core(res){


      //json data binds to variable
      vm.basics1Data = res.data;

      vm.points = 0;


      getRandom();


      //check if words are correct
      vm.wordCheck = function () {

          if(vm.wordInput === vm.test) {
              alert('good');
              getRandom();
              vm.points++;
          } else {
              alert('bad');
              getRandom();
          }

      };



      function getRandom() {
          var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
          vm.test = vm.basics1Data[random];
      }

  }
```

}

In this project I will have multiple views. Every view will have the same structure and gonna do the same thing.

Views are something like categories.

-cat1
  -cat2
  -cat3
  -and so on...

Only thing that would be different is json file.
for ex.
cat1 will have cat1.json
cat2 cat2.json etc.

Controller gonna do the same operations in every view, only on different data. How can I achieve that without copy and paste methods in controller f.ex.
WordsFactory.getWordsBasics1...
WordsFactory.getWordsBasics2...

The code that I have works, but I want to avoid copy-paste things.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: In the factory, make a function to set the JSON file. Then simply load different versions of a single view when the JSON file is different.

Comment: _Then simply load different versions of a single view when the JSON file is different._ I don't understand this at all. Can You steer me even more?

Comment: If you have 3 pages and want to render file1.json, file2.json, and file3.json then you can pass in the file as a parameter to a function in the factory based on which page was loaded. Loading a page triggers a controller function, which runs `WordsFactory.getWordsBasics1(file)`, which runs the service on an HTTP request to get a specific file. If you would like me to write the code for this let me know.

Comment: I understand the idea of passing parameters to a function and triggering controllers by rendering views. I just don't know how angular will know which json file controller should take in view1, view2, view3 and so on.. I will be truly grateful if You write the code for this. Maybe then I will get it. Thank You in advance.

Comment: I'll put up an example when I get home tonight.